# Paradox in topological phase of SSH model

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-phase, tight-binding

Consider the SSH model, i.e. the dimerized tight-binding model with Hamiltonian
$$H = \sum_i (t+\delta t) c^\dagger_{Ai} c_{Bi} + (t-\delta t) c_{A(i+1)}^\dagger c_{Bi} + \text{h.c.}.$$
This describes electrons in a crystal where the transition amplitudes between adjacent atoms alternate between $t+\delta t$ and $t-\delta t$. The unit cell is labeled by $n$, and the indices $A$ and $B$ indicate the two states in each of these cells.

Applying the Berry phase for two-state systems, one finds that the phase picked up by adiabatic transport around a Bloch band in this model is zero if $\delta t > 0$ and $\pi$ if $\delta t < 0$. This phase has apparently been observed in experiments, so it's physical.

I am really confused how there can be a difference depending on the sign of $\delta t$. If we just shift over the unit cells, then $t+ \delta t$ and $t-\delta t$ swap places, so $\delta t$ changes sign. How could this possibly change the Berry phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what is observed is the two phases difference, not each one separately. for example take look at this one:
[Direct measurement of the Zak phase in topological Bloch bands](http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v9/n12/full/nphys2790.html)

As you said, the Zak phase depends on the unit cell you choose, so it can not be physical. But the difference is physical in the sense that if you fix your unit cell and start with one system, say $\delta t >0$, and start to decrease it until $\delta t<0$, Zak phase will change $\pm \pi$ when $\delta t =0$. So these two phases are topologically different which is a physical statement.

As is noted in the aforementioned article:

> We point out that the Zak phase of each dimerization is
>   a gauge dependent quantity, i.e. it depends on the choice
>   of origin of the unit cell, however, the difference of Zak
>   phases of the two dimerizations is uniquely defined

Comment: Followed from this argument, can we say that for SSH model, it does not make sense to label one of the cases as "topological trivial"? because it depends on the choice of unit cell.